# Angular preventDefault strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, angular, events, event-handling

in my project i am using ngx-context library, which simply displays menu, however, when clicking somewhere inside of it, it closes. Thats why i decided to fix it by using event.preventDefault() + event.stopPropagation(), but for some reason it works not like i am expecting it to work

As you can see in code below i am invoking selectPositioningType() when clicking on div wrapped around mat-checkbox.

```
      <div style="width: 105%; padding: 0; margin: 0; display: flex; justify-content: center;gap: 5px"
           (click) = "selectPositioningType(positioningType, $event)">
        <mat-checkbox
          [checked] = "positioningType.ID === uwbTagsPositioningOptions.PositioningTypeID"
          [disabled] = "positioningType.ID === DRTLSPositioningTypeID">
        </mat-checkbox>
        <span>{{positioningType.Name}}</span>
      </div>
```

Inside of this function i am calling event.preventDefault(). I expect that because of the bubbling event.preventDefault() will only affect div, however, when i am toggling mat-checkbox by clicking exactly on it, it doesn't change it state even through selectPositioningType isn't invoked in that case. Just curious what can be the explanation, isn't bubbling supposed to go from bottom to top?

Btw, when using classic html input[type=checkbox] situation is the same

```
  selectPositioningType(positioningType: TagPositioningType, event: Event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    if (positioningType.ID === this.DRTLSPositioningTypeID) {
      return;
    }
    this.uwbTagsPositioningOptions = {PositioningTypeID: positioningType.ID, UwbGatewayID: null};
    localStorage.setItem('savedTagPositioningType', JSON.stringify(this.uwbTagsPositioningOptions));
}
```

Comment: it's bubbling from the checkbox to the div, where you stop it.

Comment: selectPositioningType will still be called as the click event bubbles up to the div..

Comment: @pcalkins yup, got it, btw, what if i for example place a checkboxChildren inside the checkboxParent and will click on the checkboxChildren, where in it's handler i will call event.preventDefault(), will it prevent both checkboxes of being checked?

Comment: not familiar with the mat stuff... but I don't think you can nest an input inside another input. If those were divs, preventDefault just prevents the default event of which there is none... you're calling stopPropagation which is preventing the bubbling. preventDefault on a checkbox (input element) would prevent the checking of the box.  You could still explicitly handle the click event though.  (Your click handler would still be called...)